# Does CommVault use native SQL Server backup COM objects or the VSS?

Tags: sql-server, backup

We are being told by a parent company that we will be transferring our backups to COMM Vault and are trying to gather some information regarding how the product works as far as whether it is using snapshots or the native SQL Server backup objects.  Can anyone tell me a little more about how COMM Vault backups work underneath?  A couple of us here have gone through the documentation and it appears that snapshots are not the only choice but I thought I would post the question here as well.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I used CommVault at a previous job. Version 9.4+ did both native and VSS snaps.